# how to voice frequency detect?

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing

I'm beginner android programmer. (my home language is not English so, my English is poor.)

i want to make app, get frequency recorded human voice and show note like " C3 " or "G#4"...

so, i want to detect human voice frequency , but it is too difficult.

i try use FFT, it detect piano(or guitar) sound pretty good (some part, over octave4, it didn't detect low frequency piano (or guitar) sound.), but it can't detect human voice.

(i use piano program used general midi)

I found lots of information, but i can't understand.

most of people say use pitch detect algorithm and link just wiki.

**Please tell me in detail about pitch detect algorithm.**

(actually i want example code :(

or

**is there any idea to use my app?**

HERE IS MY SOURCE CODE:

```
 public void Frequency(double[] array) {

    int sampleSize = array.length;  

    double[] win = window.generate(sampleSize);

    // signals for fft input
    double[] signals = new double[sampleSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++) {
        signals[i] = array[i] * win[i];
    }
    double[] fftArray = new double[sampleSize * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize - 1; i++) {
        fftArray[2 * i] = signals[i];
        fftArray[2 * i + 1] = 0;
    }


    FFT.complexForward(fftArray);
    getFrequency(fftArray);
}

private void getFrequency(double[] array) {

    // ========== Value ========== //

    int RATE = sampleRate;
    int CHUNK_SIZE_IN_SAMPLES = RECORDER_BUFFER_SIZE;
    int MIN_FREQUENCY = 50; // HZ
    int MAX_FREQUENCY = 2000; // HZ

    int min_frequency_fft = Math.round(MIN_FREQUENCY * CHUNK_SIZE_IN_SAMPLES / RATE);
    int max_frequency_fft = Math.round(MAX_FREQUENCY * CHUNK_SIZE_IN_SAMPLES / RATE);
    // ============================ //

    double best_frequency = min_frequency_fft;
    double best_amplitude = 0;
    for (int i = min_frequency_fft; i <= max_frequency_fft; i++) {

        double current_frequency = i * 1.0 * RATE / CHUNK_SIZE_IN_SAMPLES;

        double current_amplitude = Math.pow(array[i * 2], 2) + Math.pow(array[i * 2 + 1], 2);

        double normalized_amplitude = current_amplitude * Math.pow(MIN_FREQUENCY * MAX_FREQUENCY, 0.5) / current_frequency;

        if (normalized_amplitude > best_amplitude) {
            best_frequency = current_frequency;
            best_amplitude = normalized_amplitude;
        }
    }

    FrequencyArray[FrequencyArrayIndex] = best_frequency;
    FrequencyArrayIndex++;
}
```

I refer to this : http://code.google.com/p/android-guitar-tuner/

[Pitch_detection_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm)

use **Jtransforms**

Comment: The code you posted is only suitable for simple sounds, such as sine waves.  Real sounds are usually much more complicated.

Comment: "Please tell me in detail about pitch detect algorithm." There is lots of information on the web about pitch detection.  If you can't understand that (no offense intended here, some things just take a significant amount of specialized background to understand), how can we describe it to you in a way you can understand?  SO is a programming question and answer site, and not really an appropriate forum for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia page on pitch detection links to another Wikipedia page explaining autocorrelation: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#section_3 , which is one of many pitch estimation methods you could try.

Running the example code you posted can show that FFT peak frequency estimation is quite poor at musical pitch detection and estimation for many common pitched sounds.